# Generating all possible combinations by doing N swaps

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a list of lists `([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]...]).`

I'm trying to generate all possible lists that are reachable from this state by making N swaps on the current state, swapping an item from a list with one from a different list.

So for example - swapping a with d, b with e and f with g (notice we're looking on N swaps that are possible from THIS state)

However, I don't want to perform the actual swap, but rather generate a list of instructions for swapping that will also include the index of the `sublist`.

So, an example output with N=3 would be:

```
((1: a, 2: d), (1: b, 2: e), (1: c, 2: f))
```

(meaning swap a from `l1` with d from `l2`,
    swap b from `l1` with e from `l2`,
    swap c from `l1` with f from `l2`)

```
((1: a, 2: e), (1: b, 2: d), (1: c, 2: f))

((1: a, 3: g), (1: b, 3: h), (1: c, 3: i))

etc..
```

However, the big problem is - notice that the first swap instruction and the second one will result in **the same list**, and I'm not sure how to identify and eliminate such cases efficiently.

Right now I'm using a quite stupid recursive function which doesn't distinguish whether a swap was already performed or not. Here's the code:

```
def swap(list, num_of_swaps, current_swap, swap_instructions = []):
    for l1 in range(0,len(list)):
        for l2 in range(l1+1,len(list)):
            for e1 in list[l1]:
                for e2 in list[l2]:
                    swap_instructions.append({l1:{'add': e2, 'remove': e1},
                                              l2:{'add': e1, 'remove':e2}})

                    if current_round < max_repetitions:
                        swap(list, num_of_swaps, current_round+1, swap_instructions)

                    success = swap_and_do_checks(list, swap_instructions)
                    if success:
                        return swap_instructions

                    del swap_instructions[-1]

    return []
```

I'm not sure how to avoid repetition without it being too costly.

Will appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: could you rewrite your code with a sample and what you should get?

Comment: The list structure appears to be irrelevant for swapping. Consider representing your initial list of lists with _this_ flattened data structure: {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 3, 'h': 3, 'i': 3} Now the letters remain fixed, and each swap will be of a pair of non-equal integers. You can view candidates using `sorted(set(itertools.permutations( ... )))`.

Comment: How would you do that times N, without being left with repetitive swaps?

Comment: Anyone? I'm not sure how to use the last comment's advice

Comment: It is not clear what "possible list" is. If you start with `[[a,b,c], [d,e,f]]` is `[[d,e,f], [a,b,c]]` a possible list? If not, maybe a list isn't the best structure to consider. What about `[[c,b,a], [d,e,f]]`? is that the same as the input?